# how to decompress khr_draco_mesh_compression in a-frame (ar.js)?

Tags: compression, aframe, ar.js

I have a .gltf model loaded in A-Frame and Ar.js. It is compressed using draco (`{"extensionsUsed" : ["KHR_draco_mesh_compression"], "extensionsRequired" : ["KHR_draco_mesh_compression"]...`) but no matter what I try, it will not decompress without errors.

My code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
</head>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
<style>
  .a-enter-vr-button{
    display:none;
  }
  #arjsDebugUIContainer{
    display:none;
  }
</style>
  <a-scene embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;debugUIEnabled:false;' gltf-model="dracoDecoderPath:https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.5.6/">
    <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="modelaa" src="model.gltf"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>
      <a-marker preset='hiro'>
       
        <a-entity gltf-model="#modelaa"></a-entity>
        </a-marker>

  <a-entity camera></a-entity>
        
  </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using inline loading (`url(...)`) and it did not work. I have also tried the inspector, and it does not show any object.